# Problemas con Socket UDP en JAVA

Tags: java, socket

Estoy intentando hacer un Servidor y un Cliente con protocolo UDP. El Cliente envía un número al servidor, el Servidor lo suma y lo devuelve al cliente. Estoy teniendo unos problemas con el código que no sé solucionar.

(De momento están todos los fallos de compilación solucionados, actualizaré conforme siga trabajando y me aparezcan más dudas)

La sintaxis del cliente es: plus IP_server destiny_port M timeout

La sintaxis del Servidor es: plusd server_port N

Adjunto el código.

DataUDP (un archivo de ayuda):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class DataUDP implements Serializable{

    /**
     *Default serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DataUDP(String string) {
        this.textString = string;
    }

    public String textString;

    public byte[] toByteArray(){

        try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream (bytes);
            outputStream.writeObject(this);
            outputStream.close();
            return bytes.toByteArray();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static DataUDP fromByteArray (byte[] bytes){

        try{
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream (bytes);
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream (byteArray);
            DataUDP help = (DataUDP)inputStream.readObject();
            inputStream.close();
            return help;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class plus{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        ClientUDP(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    }

    public static void ClientUDP(String IP, String port, String number, String time) {

        final int ServerIP = Integer.parseInt(IP);
        final int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        final String M = number;
        final int Timeout = Integer.parseInt(time);

        try{
            DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(555/*Se le pasa al server por consola*/, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            DataUDP data = new DataUDP (M);
            byte[] data2send = data.toByteArray();
            DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(data2send, data2send.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), ServerPort);
            socketUDP.send(dataPacket);
            Thread.sleep(Timeout);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class plusd{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        ServerUDP(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    public static void ServerUDP(String port, String number) {

        final int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        final int N = Integer.parseInt(number);
        final String ServerIP = "localhost";
        int Sum = 0;

        try {
            DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(ServerPort, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(new byte[100], 100);

            while (true) {
                socketUDP.receive(data);
                DataUDP receivedData = DataUDP.fromByteArray(data.getData());
                Sum = Integer.parseInt(receivedData.textString) + N;
                System.out.println(Sum);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No soy un experto en java y quizás es un proyecto algo ambicioso pero quiero aprender más sobre esto.

Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda. (Conforme vaya mejorando el código y depurando lo que pueda iré añadiendo respuestas o modificaré la pregunta)

Comment: Buenas, mejora tu pregunta , indicando cual es el error que te da, donde se produce, puedes añadir las trazas de error que suelte el programa, sera mas facil ayudarte. Comprueba que los datos con los que ejecutas el cliente se recogen bien, como son la ip el puerto... puede que tu fallo este ahi

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la aclaración, he usado poco la página. He actualizado la pregunta. Uno de los principales problemas que tengo es que no sé como hacer que el cliente elija un puerto que esté libre él solo, no quiero ponerle el puerto (por ejemplo) 8000 y que esté ocupado, sino que el programa lo elija solo.

Comment: Cuando creas un servidor , le asignas un puerto donde estará escuchando. El cliente debe hacer la petición a ese puerto especifico, no a otro. No debe de elegirlo automáticamente. Tiene que ir al puerto donde este configurado el servidor.

Comment: Te recomiendo que primero pruebes el programa sin tomar esos datos del usuario. Es decir, escribiéndolos dentro del código de tu programa. De esta forma te quitaras una posible fuente de errores. Lo principal de ese ejercicio es que el cliente comunique con el servidor. No desde donde vengan los datos. Haz tu programa mas simple y te sera mas sencillo resolver errores.

Comment: Entonces, lo normal es ejecutar primero el servidor para que esté escuchando. Luego el cliente, cómo sé el puerto del servidor? Simplemente lo cojo  con "plusd.ServerPort"?

Comment: public static final int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);  Ese es el puerto que le estas configurando al servidor. Te recomiendo cambiarlo por : public static final int ServerPort = ej(8080).  Y ese es el puerto que tendrá que hacer la peticion el cliente

Comment: Efectivamente , el servidor tiene que arrancar primero. Si no esta activo el cliente nunca recibira una respuesta

Comment: En cuanto a tu error de obtener el entero de DataUDP, puesto que es una clase tuya, puedes crear un metodo que te devuelva ese entero a partir del string "textString". La forma de convertir el entero desde una cadena sería "Integer.parseInt(textString);"

Comment: Estoy revisando tu código mas detenidamente, tienes muchos errores de compilación, por lo que no te debe de compilar. Resuleve primero esos errores , y copia el codigo de nuevo. Lo estaba haciendo yo para darte una solucion. Pero son varios los que tienes y deberias de saberlos y saber resolverlos.

Comment: Actualizo ahora el código sin errores de compilación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, una vez resueltos los errores de compilación, en ejecución aparece el error :

```
java.net.BindException: La dirección ya se está usando (Bind failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:394)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:244)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:301)
    at plus.ClientUDP(plus.java:15)
    at plus.main(plus.java:8)
```

Lo que quiere decir que el cliente intentaba crear el mismo socket que el servidor, osea abria el socket como si fuese el servidor.
La solución usar el constructor por defecto de DatagramSocket que crea un socket en cualquier puerto disponible.

Te recomiendo mirar y estudiar el funcionamiento de los sockets, de forma teórica, antes de enfrentarte a la practica. Ya que cometerás errores de concepto que no sabrás o te sera dificil solucionar.

Cambie, como te dije que hicieras, los datos obtenidos del usuario por datos escritos directamente en codigo, te dejo los cambios:

Client:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class plus{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        ClientUDP("localhost", "9090", "5", "100");
    }

    public static void ClientUDP(String IP, String port, String number, String time) {

        int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        try{
            DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket();
            DataUDP data = new DataUDP (number);
            byte[] data2send = data.toByteArray();
            DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(data2send, data2send.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), ServerPort);
            socketUDP.send(dataPacket);
            Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(time));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class plusd{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        ServerUDP("9090", "5");
    }

    public static void ServerUDP(String port, String number) {

        final int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        final int N = Integer.parseInt(number);
        final String ServerIP = "localhost";
        int Sum = 0;

        try {
            DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(ServerPort, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(new byte[100], 100);

            while (true) {
                socketUDP.receive(data);
                DataUDP receivedData = DataUDP.fromByteArray(data.getData());
                Sum = Integer.parseInt(receivedData.textString) + N;
                System.out.println(Sum);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

El programa tampoco te funcionaria seguramente porque al ejecutarlo introduces ./plus 192.168.1.X como IP e intentas pasar esa cadena a entero. cuando una IP no es una variable de tipo INT.